# NextJS - How to asynchronously load webfonts with webfontloader?

Tags: javascript, next.js, webfont-loader

I have a NextJS app in which I load fonts using webfontloader

```
function load() {
  const WebFont = require("webfontloader");

  WebFont.load({
     google: {
       families: fonts
     }
    });
}
```

However, it significantly affects performance. I've read that asynchronous loading is possible according to the webfontloader documentation =>

```
<script>
   WebFontConfig = {
      typekit: { id: 'xxxxxx' }
   };

   (function(d) {
      var wf = d.createElement('script'), s = d.scripts[0];
      wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
      wf.async = true;
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
   })(document);
</script>
```

Apparently, you cannot add such scripts in the Next's Head component.

Is it possible to achieve async webfont loading in Next?

Comment: You can add scripts to the `next/head` component, you're just using a wrong syntax. Try adding backquotes around your code, e.g. ``<script>{`console.log('script')`}</script>``.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add that script to the `body` instead of the `head`. Or at least mark it with the attribute `defer` to ensure that it executes after the DOM has been loaded.

e.g.

```
<script defer>
   ...
</script>
```